# git aware but (remote) svn ignore

Tags: git, git-svn, svnignore

I have a publicly hosted svn repository on google code, however locally I switched to git because of various reasons. I'm currently the only developer with access to the googlecode repo so no need to do fetches. All commits go via a dev branch, to the master branch to svn, with `git svn dcommit`. All well. Now i'm in the situation that I've some files locally in version control with git, but I do not EVER want them to make public available.

So I had an idea: I create a directory private and add a svn:ignore "private/*" property to my svn repo. But than after

```
git svn dcommmit
```

I get an error: Merge conflict during commit: File or directory '.' is out of date; try updating: resource out of date; try updating at /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 574

I tried importing the svn:ignore property into .git/info/exclude but that excludes all my git files in the 'private' from git which is definitely not what I want.

[08-06-2011]

I think the error is not because of the svn:ignore, it seems that git svn completely ignore the svn:ignore, but due to some other yet unknown reason. The question becomes: is it possible to exclude paths from `git svn dcommit` in the same way as it is possible to exclude paths from `git svn fetch` with --ignore-path

Comment: tried a pull and merge since you added that property?

Comment: did do: git svn rebase / git svn fetch, not sure how a pull is working with git-svn?

Comment: I meant a fetch, sorry.  Was taking a shot in the dark to see if there was a quick easy way out for ya; looks like this is one for a git pro.  It's a good question though, so +1.

Comment: Don't forget to stop 'following' those private files in the public repo.

Answer (score 1):

git-svn ignores svn:ignore but [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) doesn't if you checkout your repository using SmartGit. It converts it to corresponding .gitignore files and vice versa.
So I would recommend you to use SmartGit instead of git-svn.

Answer (score 0):

The [git-svn man](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) page indicates this is possible with the following config key:

```
svn-remote.<name>.ignore-paths
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and i think I've also seen this flag during my quest. At the time I read it as a one way block: from svn -> git. 
`This allows one to specify a Perl regular expression that will cause skipping of all matching paths FROM CHECKOUT FROM SVN. The --ignore-paths option should match for every fetch (including automatic fetches due to clone, dcommit, rebase, etc) on a given repository.` 
I have re read it again, and I still hold to my original believe, But english is not my mothertongue and in general i tend to misread man pages (especially git's)